# TestNG - Dataprovider at Class level test annocation

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I will try and explain my scenario here so that it's clear what I want.

I have a set of methods within a Class which performs a few tests, they are all related to each other and have to be run in a sequence, so they have `DependsOnMethod` in their `@Test` annotation. I am also using a `DataProvider` which returns 7 values per test (n rows & 7 columns). Now when I put this data provider at the method level, it reads all the rows and executes Method 1 with every set of data available, then moves onto next method.

I want this sequence changed, I want it to run Method 1 (data set 1), Method 2 (Data set 1), Method 1 (Data set 2), ... I know this a question many people have. The reason I am posting this question again is because I have tried all the suggested ideas.

When using Factory annotation, it makes my test to not start at all in Eclipse, giving a `NullPointerException`. I use an `@BeforeClass` annotation which is never run if I use the factory annotation. I am giving this factory annotation on Constructor of the class.

I have tried the `group-by-instance` flag in the testng.xml file but that fails too: it runs the tests in the same sequence.

Please can someone explain this whole thing in the correct order for me? If possible with an example, as I'm sure this can be achieved but I guess I am missing something somewhere.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I am not very good with Java and I been using TestNG for the past 2-3 weeks.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

With the anotation "DataSet" :
JavaDoc :

```
org.unitils.dbunit.annotation.DataSet
@Target(value={METHOD, TYPE})
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Inherited
```

Annotation indicating that a data set should be loaded before the test run.

If a class is annotated, a test data set will be loaded before the execution of each of the test methods in the class. A data set file name can explicitly be specified. If no such file name is specified, first a data set named 'classname'.'testmethod'.xml will be tried, if no such file exists, 'classname'.xml will be tried. If that file also doesn't exist, an exception will be thrown. Filenames that start with '/' are treated absolute. Filenames that do not start with '/', are relative to the current class.

A test method can also be annotated with DataSet in which case you specify the dataset that needs to be loaded before this test method is run. Again, a file name can explicitly be specified or if not specified, the default will be used: first 'classname'.'methodname'.xml and if that file does not exist 'classname'.xml.

Examples:

```
 @DataSet
  public class MyTestClass extends UnitilsJUnit3 {

      public void testMethod1(){
      }

     @DataSet("aCustomFileName.xml")
      public void testMethod2(){
      }
  }
```

Will load a data set file named MyTestClass.xml or MyTestClass-testMethod1.xml for testMethod1 in the same directory as the class. And for testMethod2 a data set file named aCustomFileName.xml in the same directory as the class is loaded.

```
  public class MyTestClass extends UnitilsJUnit3 {

      public void testMethod1(){
      }

     @DataSet
      public void testMethod2(){
      }
  }
```

Will not load any dataset for testMethod1 (there is no class level data set). Will load a data set file named MyTestClass.xml or MyTestClass.testMethod2.xml for testMethod2.
Author:

Filip Neven

Tim Ducheyne

Comment: Hi Benoit,  Thanks for your reply.  
I am using CSV files to store test data, so dont think this will be of much help to me. I wont be able to switch to XML that easily.  
Just out of curiosity, will using the Dataset annotation run all the methods in a class with the first row of data first and then pick up the next row of data data in the XML and run it on all the methods again?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to invoke these methods manually:

```
@Test(dataProvider = ...)
public void f(int n1, int n2) {
    method1(n1, n2);
    method2(n1, n2);
}
```

However, grouping by instances should have worked, can you email a small class to the testng-users list so I can reproduce it?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Cedric, thanks a lot for your reply, good to see the maker himself helping us out, your product is simply awesome, wish I just knew a little bit more about Java :).   

This idea is good, but then this will disable the test annotation against these methods I beleive, but I still give it a try.  

If this does not help me, i will send in a sample class to the testng-users group.  

Thanks again and I will keep you posted.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, but it seems to be running the tests one extra time, like if I have two rows of data and if I use a method to read these values and then call the remaining @test methods in this method, then it will execute them twice and since the other methods also have test annotation against them, its getting called again with the last row of data. Moreover this is also not helping me with reporting, because I would like to know which test has failed and with which row of data. I will mail a sample project to Testng-user group in sometime. Thanks, John

Comment: If you're following my suggestion, make sure you remove the @Test tag from method1 and method2, or TestNG will run them as well (which would explain the double run you're seeing).

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean, I have actually combined these method into one big method now, so that this problem does not happen. I guess I will be programmatically handling the flow, but I have to think over it, but would have loved to see it working with TestNG, hard luck :(. BTW I have sent a sample class to tetng-user google group, if you get time, please have a look and reply. Thank you.