# TestNG Executing Test One Iteration at a time with DataProvider

Tags: java, testng

I am using data provider to pass data to each of the test methods. Let's assume there are 2 rows in the data provider.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "TestData")
public void firstTest(String data){
   //Code
}

@Test(dataProvider = "TestData")
public void secondTest(String data){
   //Code
}

@Test(dataProvider = "TestData")
public void thirdTest(String data){
   //Code
}
```

Currently all iterations of single test method runs and then the second test method runs... For example:

```
firstTest()
firstTest()

secondTest()
secondTest()

thirdTest()
thirdTest()
```

But I want to run in the following order.

```
firstTest()
secondTest()
thirdTest()

firstTest()
secondTest()
thirdTest()
```

Below is the xml for TestNG.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Test-Automation" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" verbose="1">
    <test name="Suite Test" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" verbose="1">
        <listeners>
             <listener class-name="GroupByInstanceEnabler"></listener>
        </listeners>

        <classes>
            <class name="SampleTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="firstTest"/>
                    <include name="secondTest"/>
                    <include name="thirdTest"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The GroupByListener method is defined as below.

```
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteListener;

public class GroupByInstanceEnabler implements ISuiteListener {

    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        suite.getXmlSuite().setGroupByInstances(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {

    }
}
```

I have checked the below 2 questions and it does not seem to work for me.

[TestNG iterate over test data instead of test methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783613/testng-iterate-over-test-data-instead-of-test-methods)

[TestNG - Dataprovider at Class level test annocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893474/testng-dataprovider-at-class-level-test-annocation)

http://fruzenshtein.com/testng-dataprovider-run-tests-sequentially/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a TestNG factory that is powered by a data provider.

Here's a sample that shows you how to use TestNG factories coupled with a data provider.

```java
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn48399410;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTestClass {
    private int iteration;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
    public SampleTestClass(int iteration) {
        this.iteration = iteration;
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        System.err.println("firstTest() running for iteration #" + iteration);
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        System.err.println("secondTest() running for iteration #" + iteration);
    }

    @Test
    public void thirdTest() {
        System.err.println("thirdTest() running for iteration #" + iteration);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public static Object[][] getData() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {1},
                {2},
                {3}
        };
    }
}
```

And here's the suite xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="48399410_Suite" parallel="false" verbose="2">
    <test name="48399410_test" verbose="2" group-by-instances="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn48399410.SampleTestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The attribute `group-by-instances=true` would have an effect only when you are working with factories. It would cause TestNG to run all the methods within a test class instance together (which is apt in this case).

Refer to the [official TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories) on factories for more information.

Here's the output

```
...
... TestNG 6.13.1 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...
firstTest() running for iteration #2
secondTest() running for iteration #2

thirdTest() running for iteration #2
firstTest() running for iteration #3
secondTest() running for iteration #3
thirdTest() running for iteration #3
firstTest() running for iteration #1
secondTest() running for iteration #1
thirdTest() running for iteration #1
PASSED: firstTest
PASSED: secondTest
PASSED: thirdTest
PASSED: firstTest
PASSED: secondTest
PASSED: thirdTest
PASSED: firstTest
PASSED: secondTest
PASSED: thirdTest

===============================================
    48399410_test
    Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

===============================================
48399410_Suite
Total tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I am getting "org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process" exception. Not all my methods runs with data provider. It works fine when I remove the constructor method having @Factory annotation.

Comment: @Purus - I didn't quite understand your statement. If you would like two or more methods to iterate on each of the data sets, then the only way to achieve that is using a Factory coupled with a data provider.

Comment: Krishnan: I have same pogram as you mentioned above. But, I want results separated for each instance. 3 tescases under each instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Krishnan Mahadevan , how can i run the iteration for a data provider using an array inside test class.

for Example 
@Test (dataProvider="dp")
    public void firstTest() {
        System.err.println("firstTest() running for iteration #" + iteration);
        array of data provider elements ? 
    }
is it feasible via dataprovider ?
```