# Wrong number of arguments error for factory method

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am getting error `wrong number of arguments` for this code. What is wrong here? I need to get data from an excel sheet and provide it `MyClass` through dataprovider. The `@Factory` annotation is used on the constructor because I need to use this data for different test methods in my class.

```
public class MyClass { 

    HashMap<String, Object> datamap;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
    public MyClass(HashMap<String, Object> datamap) {
        this.datamap = datamap;
    }
```

--

```
@DataProvider(name="dp")
    public static Object[][] getData() {
        ExcelData ed = new ExcelData("filename","sheetname");
        Object[][] dataObj = ed.dataObj;
        return dataObj;
    }
```

--

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelData {

    public Object[][] dataObj = null;

    public ExcelData(String filename, String sheetname) {
        String data, val;
        HashMap<String, Object> testdata;
        ArrayList<String> imagelocs;
        File file = new File(filename);

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetname);

            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
            int dataCount = row.getLastCellNum()-1;
            int varCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
            dataObj = new Object[dataCount][varCount];

            for (int j=0; j < dataCount; j++) {
                int i = 0;
                testdata = new HashMap<>();
                imagelocs = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (true) {
                    row = sheet.getRow(i);
                    try {
                        data = row.getCell(0).toString();
                        val = row.getCell(j+1).toString();
                    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (data.toString().equals("Images")) {
                        imagelocs.add(val.toString());
                    } else {
                        testdata.put(data, val);
                    }

                    i++;

                }
                testdata.put("imagelocs", imagelocs);
                dataObj[j][0] = testdata;

            }
            wb.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e){ 
             System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");
        }
    }

}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
The factory method class MyClass() threw an exception
    at org.testng.internal.FactoryMethod.invoke(FactoryMethod.java:197)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processFactory(TestNGClassFinder.java:223)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processMethod(TestNGClassFinder.java:179)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processClass(TestNGClassFinder.java:171)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:121)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:370)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:192)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class MyClass
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.FactoryMethod.invoke(FactoryMethod.java:183)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:24)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: except the fact that `getData` returns a 2d array while `MyClass` expects a `HashMap` I dont see any other issue so far

Comment: it would help alot if you provide the error stack trace in your post

Comment: @NikosM. I have added the stack trace.

Comment: Yeap read my 1st comment

Comment: Are you sure that the dataprovider will pass the data in the constructor in this way? This is the whole problem, but since I dont know the framework you use, it is hard to tell more

Comment: @NikosM. I got the idea from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399410/testng-executing-test-one-iteration-at-a-time-with-dataprovider

Comment: I got it to work finally. I changed the last line in `ExcelData` class to `dataObj[j] = new Object[] {testdata};`